# How to index IN/OR in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have query that use IN and OR in clause and cant manage to use index.

Any ideas how to rework query to use index ?

I tried with UNION as @ErgestBasha suggest but no results found

Query

```
   SELECT DISTINCT name, search_name, priority
    FROM search_category_synonymous scs
      LEFT JOIN search_category sc ON sc.category_id = scs.category_id
      LEFT JOIN category_path cp ON (scs.category_id = cp.path_id)
    WHERE 
      name IN('car red','red car','car','red') 
        OR 
      synonymous IN('car red','red car','car','red') 
    AND sc.status = 1
    GROUP BY sc.category_id
```

Explain

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key          key_len    ref     rows    Extra   
 1  SIMPLE           scs    ALL     synonymous      NULL         NULL       NULL    138809  Using temporary; Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE           sc     ref     category_id     category_id   4         scs.category_id     1   Using where
 1  SIMPLE           cp     ref     path_id         path_id       4         scs.category_id     1   Using where
```

Index

```
    ALTER TABLE `oc_search_category`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
      ADD KEY `name` (`name`),
      ADD KEY `priority` (`priority`);

    --------------------------------------------------------------

      
      ALTER TABLE `oc_search_category_synonymous`
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        ADD KEY `synonymous` (`synonymous`),
        ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`);
        
    -----------------------------------------------------------------

    ALTER TABLE `oc_category_path`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`path_id`),
      ADD KEY `path_id` (`path_id`,`category_id`);
```

Comment: You need to add each table description to check the indexes. Maybe it will be slightly faster if you change `OR` to `UNION ` condition

Comment: @ErgestBasha done topic updated, i cant manage to do it with UNION always no results returned